# SendKeys.SendWait doesn't work on Stella Emulator

Tags: c#, emulation

Have tried a couple of days without any sucess.
I'm just trying to send keystrokes to a process, which is an Atari video game emulator (Stella).

My app is a Console Application in C# made with VS 2013, running in 64 bit Windows 7.

Method **Sendkeys.Wait** works fine with almost any app, e.g. calc, excel, notepad, etc.

Tried some approachs, such as:

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

static private void Teste(string key)
{
    IntPtr stellaHandle = FindWindow("SDL_app", "Stella 4.6.7: \"River Raid (1982) (Activision)\"");

    SetForegroundWindow(stellaHandle);
    SendKeys.SendWait(key);
}
```

I compiled in Any CPU, x86 and x64, used 32 and 64 bit versions of Stella, tried also with an other emulator (Z26), even tried with a javascript emulator running in Firefox (http://www.virtualatari.org).

None of my approachs worked. Get the window is ok. Set the window as foreground also ok.

Any idea? Someone faced such a problem before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit: Send Keys to Chrome running Atari emulator solved the problem for me. (Still working in image recognition and AI to play the game, when finished I will publish video and code online to share)